# Setting Nvidia Kernel Module Parameters

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I'm trying to set some kernel module parameters for the nvidia kernel module (specifically `NVreg_RegisterForACPIEvents=1` and `NVreg_EnableMSI=1`), but no matter which method I try for setting them, they don't show up as being set with the command `# systool -vm nvidia`. I've tried adding conf files to both `/etc/modprobe.d` and `/etc/modules-load.d`, as well as add them to the kernel command line in the grub configuration, but none of these method seem to work. All of these methods are based on my experience with Arch, so I was wondering, is there some sort of special Ubuntu way of configuring kernel module params? Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Comment: So I can't make a comment, but exact same problem here. nvidia_drm modesetting shows up fine with systool -vm nvidia_drm, but systool -vm nvidia doesn't show any of the parameters I've added. The two you mentioned, and others like NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocation. From Google I found a couple other people not being able to do the same thing with parameters. Maybe a bug report with Nvidia is the way to go forward with this?

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with same problem, while trying to change NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers parameter.

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-err_nvgpuctrperm-permission-issue-performance-counters

Above link might be helpful. To change parameter temporally Do as instructed in the link. When you try to unload nvidia module you might encounter below error.

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia is in use
```

Then you should turn nvidia-persistenced.service off.

```
systemctl stop nvidia-persistenced.service
```

Then you could proceed

```
modprobe -r nvidia_modest nvidia
```

Then you could reload nvidia module with parameter

```
modprobe nvidia [parameter_name]=[value]
```

I do not know why paramter are not shown in `systool -vm` but changed parameter takes its effect.

Otherwise
if you want to add config in `/etc/modprobe.d/` you should rebuild initrd with `update-initramfs -u`